# Power analysis in a mixed model with a within-between subjects interaction

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, statistical-power

I have data from an experiment in which each subject was assigned to one of 4 experimental conditions (CONDITION, a between-subject factor), and then faced 4 similar but distinct tasks (TASK, a within-subject factor). My DV is a continuous variable (DV), and the hypothesis is with respect to an interaction between CONDITION and TASK.

For the analysis I am using the lme4 package in R, and the model looks like this:

```
m = lmer(DV ~ CONDITION * TASK + (1+ORDER|SUBJ), data)
```

where ORDER is simply the order by which a subject faced the task (1, 2, 3, or 4), and SUBJ is a unique subject Id.

This was an exploratory study, and I now would like to use it to perform a power analysis for a larger study. My question regards the way to perform a power analysis considering my goal is to find a significant interaction between a between-subject factor and a within-subject factor.

I tried looking at package SIMR, which seems the most flexible one for performing power analysis of mixed models, but cannot figure out how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe you could try [GPower](http://www.gpower.hhu.de/en.html). Please see the page 182 of [this](http://www.gpower.hhu.de/fileadmin/redaktion/Fakultaeten/Mathematisch-Naturwissenschaftliche_Fakultaet/Psychologie/AAP/gpower/GPower3-BRM-Paper.pdf), in which the table 3 talked about the between-within two factor ANOVA power analysis.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the quick reference. This is very helpful. The one thing I am missing from this document to complete the analysis is determination of "nonsphericity correction ε". Can you perhaps refer to something on that?

Comment: Please have a look at https://statistics.laerd.com/statistical-guides/sphericity-statistical-guide.php. It talks about how to calculate and correct for the sphericity. Sometimes people just use 0.75.

Comment: Great, thank you! (how can I accept a comment as an answer?)

Comment: Glad to help. I am afraid you cannot accept a comment as an answer. No worries!